# How can I get the result to return '0' instead of NaN if nothing is entered into the field.

Tags: javascript, html

If the field is left blank, it will return NaN as the average. How can I get this to return 0 instead?

This is what I have for my HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Average Numbers </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="arrays.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function ShowAvg()
 // Assumes: numsBox contains a sequence of numbers
 // Results: displays the average of the numbers in outputDiv
 {
   var str, strArray, numArray;

   str = document.getElementById('numsBox').value;
    if ( isNan(str)){
    document.getElementById('numArray').value = '0';
    }
   strArray = str.split(/[, \t\n]+/);   // SPLIT STRING INTO AN ARRAY
   numArray = ParseArray(strArray);     // STORE ARRAY VALUES AS NUMS4

   document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = 
       'The average of [' + numArray + '] is ' + Average(numArray); 
 }
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <p>
 Enter numbers: <input type="text" id="numsBox" size=40 value="">
 </p>
 <p>
 <input type="button" value="Compute the Average" onclick="ShowAvg();">
 </p>
 <div id="outputDiv"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is my javascript file:

```
function Acronym(phrase) 
// Assumes: phrase is a string of words, separated by whitespace 
// Returns: the acronym made up of first letters from the words 
{
var words, acronym, index, nextWord;

words = phrase.split(/[ \t\n]+/);         // CONVERT phrase TO AN ARRAY 
acronym = '';                               // INITIALIZE THE acronym

index = 0;                              // START AT FIRST WORD 
while (index < words.length) {          // AS LONG AS WORDS LEFT 
nextWord = words[index];                //     GET NEXT WORD
acronym = acronym + nextWord.charAt(0); //   ADD FIRST CHAR OF WORD 
index = index + 1;                      //   GO ON TO NEXT WORD 
}
return acronym.toUpperCase();               // RETURN UPPER CASE acronym
}


function ParseArray(strArray) 
// Assumes: strArray is an array of strings representing numbers 
// Returns: a copy of strArray with items converted to numbers 
{
var numArray, index; 

numArray = [ ];                     // CREATE EMPTY ARRAY TO STORE COPY

index = 0;                          // FOR EACH ITEM IN strArray
while (index < strArray.length) {   //   CONVERT TO NUMBER AND COPY
numArray[index] = parseFloat(strArray[index]); 
index = index + 1; 
}
return numArray;                        // FINALLY, RETURN THE COPY
}


function Average(numArray)
// Assumes: numArray is an array of numbers
// Returns: average of the numbers in numArray
{
var sum, index;

sum = 0;                             // INITIALIZE sum

index = 0;                           // START AT FIRST NUMBER
while (index < numArray.length) {    // AS LONG AS NUMBERS LEFT
sum = sum + numArray[index];        //   ADD NUMBER TO sum
index = index + 1;                 //   GO ON TO NEXT NUMBER
}
return sum/numArray.length;          // RETURN AVERAGE
}
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help. I'm a noob at this and have been struggling for hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue rather than dumping a bunch of code.

Answer (score 1):

to make a long story short, just add

```
value = value || 0;
```

for a default value.

I got following problems

1. `isNan()` should be `isNaN()`
2. `document.getElementById('numArray').value = '0';` is not working, because its a button, not an input field, Use instead `document.getElementById('numsBox').value = '0';`.

Answer (score 0):

Longer answer:  In your js file, replace

```
return numArray;
}
```

with

```
avgNum = sum/numArray.length;
if (avgNum != avgNum) {
    avgNum = 0;
}
return avgNum;          // RETURN AVERAGE
}
```

You will still need to change the str NaN display in the html file (I would just take it out and say the average is: since the numbers are still shown at the top).  The reason this works is that the only this NaN is not equal to is itself (which is sooo weird).  Code On!

Comment: I had no  success with either method. Is it possible to attack this differently? Maybe i'm not doing this the best way...

Comment: This code was to replace avgNum return in Average, not in the ParseArray function.